# SMTP Unencrypted connection in alertmanger

Tags: email, kubernetes, smtp, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm facing an issue after configuring email in alertmanager as of the below log

```
level=warn ts=2022-04-12T16:35:29.370Z caller=notify.go:724 component=dispatcher receiver=email integration=email[0] msg="Notify attempt failed, will retry later" attempts=1 err="*smtp.plainAuth auth: unencrypted connection"
```

This is what I have configured in alertmanger:

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
  smtp_require_tls: false
  smtp_smarthost: smtp.demo.solutions:587
  smtp_from: coco.mail@demo.solutions
  smtp_auth_username: coco.mail@demo.solutions
  smtp_auth_password: mail@123
  http_config:
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
route:
  group_by: ['...']
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 12h
  receiver: 'email'
  routes:
  - match:
      alertname: Watchdog
    receiver: 'null'
receivers:
- name: 'null'
- name: 'email'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'sample@gmail.com, demo@gmail.com, choudary@demo.solutions'
    headers:
      subject: '{{ template "custom_mail_subject" . }}'
    html: '{{ template "custom_mail_html" . }}'
templates:
- '/etc/alertmanager/config/mail.tmpl'
```

So what could be the issue and solution to it.

Comment: Have you checked this [issue](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/1358) for Alertmanager on GitHub?

Comment: Yes I did checked it. Still the same.

Comment: Ok, can you add more details? What have you tried and what have you achieved (result)?